# Gatsby GraphQL cannot query field "url" on type "File" of Strapi

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I'm making a blog with Gatsby front-end, Strapi back-end. I made a query in component with StaticQuery

```
query={graphql`
        query {
          allStrapiArticle {
            edges {
              node {
                strapiId
                title
                category {
                  name
                }
                image {
                  url
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      `}
```

All of field is work fine without `image{url}`. I got error: `error  Cannot query field "url" on type "File"  graphql/template-strings`. How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Does the field exist?

Comment: Yes, of course, I added a field with Image type, single Image, required. Also create a article with image

Comment: You should probably query by `publicURL` instead of `url` inside the `image` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite you've created an image object with an `url` field in Strapi, Strapi + Gatsby downloads it and you must change a bit your query.

At this point, all your images belong to `gatsby-source-filesystem` so they must be queried in a different way. Of course, you can get the `url` but your data structure may differ from the one you've created in Strapi's back office. In other words, the field you are looking for is inside another object, in this case, the `publicURL` will contain your desired `url` value. Here's a sample of how to get one or multiple images:

```
    singleImage {
     publicURL
    }
    multipleImages {
      localFile {
        publicURL
      }
    }
```

*Reference: https://github.com/strapi/gatsby-source-strapi*

Take a look at the autocompletion when you run a gatsby develop under `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to test your GraphQL query, it may help you to get the fields you need.

[This tutorial](https://strapi.io/blog/building-a-static-website-using-gatsby-and-strapi) also points out some interesting stuff.

If you want to use a `gatsby-image`-based image, you can use:

```
  image {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 960) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
```

Then it should be used in a loop something like (with `gatsby-image` usage):

```
<Img fluid={data.allStrapiArticle.edges[position].index.image.childImageSharp.fluid} />
```

Answer (score 4):

I have faced this problem too. Tutorial on [Strapi](https://strapi.io/blog/build-a-static-blog-with-gatsby-and-strapi) suggest to query with 'url' but it's wrong.

The right way to query is to do:

```
      allStrapiArticle {
        edges {
          node {
            strapiId
            title
            category {
              name
            }
            image {
              publicURL
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

In order to display image, don't forget to swap **url** into **publicURL** like that:

```
  <img
    src={article.node.image.publicURL}
    alt={article.node.image.publicURL}
    height="100"
  />
```